# show certain data according to logged in webuser in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners, servletcontextlistener

I built a dynamic web application with JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 5.2 (community edition). It's running on an IBM Websphere v8.5.

My web application uses a p:dataTable to populate some data. Each webuser should only see its own data and can add some records to it. The webuser's name or id can caught by `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser()`.
A login.xhtml mask is forbidden, because of some constraints.

How and where to filter for the different webuser's views? There are JSF phaseListener, ServletContextListener, HttpSessionListener or ServletRequestListener or some Filters. What components should I use?

I hope that someone can help me a little bit.

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding your concrete problem. How exactly are you having trouble to straightforwardly call a DB service method, passing the current logged-in user as argument, so it could use that in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Thanks for comment BalusC! My p:datatable's attribute is value="#{dtPaymentView.payments}" and payments it's only a List<Payment>. I think that the getRemoteUser() comes too late and the website is already rendered. Hmm.. so far is my understanding, but I'm not sure! I will try to bind p:dataTable's value to a method which catches the remote_user, than calls the suitable data with HQL and returns the right data list to my p:dataTable.

Comment: Hm? How are you filling the `payments`? You're calling a service method for that in bean's postconstruct, right? Just pass the logged-in user as argument of that service method. You already know for long how to grab it from the faces context.

Comment: I call a getAllPayments() of my PaymentDAO object to fill payments. I will try it now! :)

Comment: It works! Thanks! :D ..sry I'm not aware of having access to remote user at this code position.. ohh sry man, my fault!